# MongoDB PHP: Insert if not exists equivalent

Tags: php, mongodb

I use MongoDB together with PHP. To create a unique document for each user, I set the username to unique with

```
$db->ensureIndex(array("username" => 1), array("unique" => 1, "dropDups" => 1));
```

However, if there is a duplicate, the _id value that is being returned for the user is that of the record which got never created and not that of the record which already exists in the db.

Here's the entire function:

```
function register_user($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email)
{    
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->users->details;
$db->ensureIndex(array("username" => 1), array("unique" => 1, "dropDups" => 1));
$user_doc = array( "username" => $username, "password" => $password, "first_name" => $first_name, "last_name" => $last_name, "email" => $email);
$db->insert($user_doc);
return $user_doc["_id"]; // here i return the _id
}
```

How would I go about creating a user database, that has no duplicate usernames?

**EDIT:**

Here's my temporary solution. I put it right where the insert used to be.

```
try 
  {
      $db->insert($user_doc,array('safe'=>1));
  }
  catch ( MongoCursorException $e ) 
  {
      // if this did not work, we already have that user inside and want to get his _id
      $user = $db->findOne(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
      return $user["_id"];
  }
```

If I try to insert it with the safe option, it would always die. Using the try-catch procedure, I try to insert and if it does not work, manually find the _id by username. I'm still not satisfied with this solution, so it would be great if more proficient MongoDB users could give some advice.

Comment: why not check if a record using that id already exists first? Also, you could make use of MongoCollection::update() in combination with the 'upsert' option set to true. This would create a new record if a criteria is not found. The criteria in your case would be the username being passed. take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

Answer (score 0):

First off, you always need that `try...catch`. The reason you were getting the wrong `_id` for `$user_doc` is simply that the driver creates it before sending it to the database. So even if the insert fails it's still on the document.

> How would I go about creating a user database, that has no duplicate usernames?

I would start by over-writing the `_id` field with the user name. The `_id` is auto-generated as a convenience, but you can set it yourself before you insert.

You will still need to use the `try...catch` but you will get a specific duplicate key error. You can then use this to correctly handle the case of *"that user name already exists"*.

Comment: a downvoter who added no comments and did not bother to add another answers either. <sarcasm>brilliant</sarcasm>

Comment: that is putting it mildly. If an answer is wrong a user that finds this page on google should get some indication as the the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I manage to insert if not exists.

```
    $db->update(
            array('email' => $email),
            array('$setOnInsert' => array('email' => $email)),
            array('upsert' => true)
        );
```

This basically just updates when the record exists ("updating" to what it's already set to and [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) does nothing), but if it doesn't exist, mongo upserts a new record then creates the new key and assigns the value.